# Identifying late 80s early 90s sci-fi movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been trying to identify this movie that I saw as a child for years, with no luck. I remember that a non-military ship visits a shipwreck and the crew downloads the logs from the main computer that's still operational. The logs shows that the wreck has been visited by a number of tubular, hexagon (octagon?) base vessels. Soon after these tubular ships show up and it turns out they are parts of a modular battleship as they lock to each other. They are asked to surrender, and they pretend to do so while they construct a "lightning cannon" that they use when the battleship attempts to dock. A person whom they probably picked up along the way built the weapon and dies when he holds a broken panel together by his hands when they fire it.
Anybody could help me figure out which movie is this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Some more details would be helpful. Is this an American / English language film? Live action or animated? Any memory as to possible actors in the film? - Some helpful guidelines on how to ask a good identification question with higher odds of getting answered: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: Sound like the end of Titan A.E. :-)

Comment: It is a live-action, most likely American movie. Unfortunately I cannot recall any of the actors, then I would have had a starting point. I can only recall a few key scenes that I described. It is really annoying that I haven't come across it ever since. Of course the attacking ship is paralysed and the bad guy loses at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, a question where the answer is [Earth Star Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager) (1988)!

- "Tubular ships", "modular battleship": The enemy ships come together to form a mega-ship, of which the Earth Star Voyager was intended to become a part of.
- "Lightning cannon": The heroes rig up a solar reflector laser-type weapon, as well as a railgun in an airlock
- "A person whom they probably picked up along the way built the weapon and dies when he holds a broken panel together by his hands when they fire it.": Yes, except he

  > doesn't die (good guys didn't die in Disney movies back then)

The full movie (which was a 2-part pilot) is available on YouTube:

Comment: This is it, thank you!